# MySQL - "view" for a specific cell

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a MySQL table with some columns and rows. Lets call it A.
I would like to create something like a "view" for a specific cell inside this table.
I mean, I would like, for example, the value of the cell to be any value selected from table B and divided by some value taken from table C.
And I want this cell always be up to date.

Is it possible in MySQL? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

That is called a join

```
select a.*, b/c as calc_column
from a
left join b on a.some_col = b.other_col
left join c on a.col3 = c.col4
```